# difference between solid crescendo hairpin, dotted and dashed crec hairpins?

Tags: sheet-music, sibelius

I noticed music software sibelius has 3 different types of hairpins when it comes to crescendos. Solid line, dotted and dashed. What is the difference between the 3?

Comment: Do you count the wedge-shaped (i.e. < ) one as a hairpin? I find that harder to read when stretched across multiple systems/lines.

Comment: A dotted/dashed hairpin is usually the suggestion of an editor. It appears where the original music had no hairpin. If the composer didn't write one, the editor has to decide whether s/he didn't *want* one or simply forgot. It's the same with dotted/dashed *slurs*. I don't know what distinguishes dotted ones from dashed ones. I thought it was just personal preference.

Comment: Exactly what @OldBrixtonian said. Further you can assign any sort of function to these hairpins as long as you properly document this.

Answer (score 2):

A dotted/dashed hairpin is usually an editor's suggestion.

It occurs where there is no hairpin in the original, but where the editor thinks there *ought* to be one. Perhaps similar material elsewhere in the piece **is** accompanied by a hairpin. Or, if it's an ensemble or orchestral piece, perhaps the *other* instruments have hairpins in ***their*** parts at this point.

The editor has to decide whether the composer **chose** not to put a hairpin here, or simply **forgot** to do one!

It's exactly the same with dotted/dashed **slurs**.

Some editions may include footnotes explaining, for example, "Not present in the composer's MS, but included in every published edition." If the musician is persuaded, s/he will observe the mark. If it's in an orchestral part, the section leader routinely makes such decisions.

These signs may be made of dots or dashes, according to the publisher's house style or the composer/arranger's preference. In the absence of an explanatory note they mean the same.

As Lazy observed, composers can designate anything to mean anything:
*Notes marked with a dashed slur are to be played with schmaltzy portamento.

Dotted crescendo/diminuendo hairpins mean raise/lower your horn.*
Etc.

Comment: One example where using multiple hairpin types as composer could be if you have an instrument with more expressive degrees of freedom than just loudness. E.g. on a percussive instrument you might often go louder by hitting harder or by simply playing the instrument in a different spot (e.g. more in the middle). So if you want to make use of these possibilities you might use a normal hairpin for a change in how hard you play and a dashed hairpin for changing the position you play in and such stuff. The important thing is that there is some sort of annotation that explains what you actually want